# Sending a PDF from client to server isn't working with stream.pipe(res) in Ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, timeout, digital-ocean, node-streams

I have an application that makes a PDF and sends it to the client using node js. The application works perfectly locally but when I host it in a Ubuntu server in Digital Ocean, the endpoint that generates the PDF isn't working

This is the code that sends the PDF to the client :

```
pdf.create(html, options).toStream((err, stream)=> {
            if (err) {
              res.json({
                message: 'Sorry, we were unable to generate pdf',
              });
            }
            stream.pipe(res)

          });
```

in the client side this how i communicate with the endpoint

```
  genratePdf({ commit }, data) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:1337/getpdf', data,{ responseType:'arraybuffer' }).then((response) => {
      let blob = new Blob([response.data],{type:'application/pdf'})
      var link=document.createElement('a');
      link.href=URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download="Report_"+new Date()+".pdf";
      link.click();


    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
```

When i run it locally it works perfectly: 
[image]

but when I host in a Ubuntu Digital Ocean droplet the other endpoint work but the generated PDF one is not working and it shows me that error 
[image]

I think it's a timeout problem the app does not wait for the stream to finish to pipe it in res.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually an error occuring in the generation of your pdf but because you are not returning when handling error, it still executes the `stream.pipe` statement.

Change your code to this :

```
pdf.create(html, options).toStream((err, stream)=> {
   if (err) {
       console.error(err);
       return res.json({
           message: 'Sorry, we were unable to generate pdf',
       });
   }
   return stream.pipe(res)
});
```

Notice I added a `console.error(err);`, it might help you to debug further. But I think the library you are using uses PhantomJS, might be an error with it as PhantomJS must be compiled for the arch.

Try doing `rm -Rf ./node_modules && npm i`